# onclick Submit button AND $_SESSION['variable']=1, can be combined?

Tags: php, javascript, session, onclick

I've been reading related posts about this but I still don't get the right answers. I applied their advice but failed in achieving what I want. I wanted to achieve this: When I click the Submit button, I'd like $_SESSION['roomno'] = 400 and $_SESSION['chairnum']=5 be passed to another page in PHP.

partial monica.php code:

```
<div id="popupContact">
        <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
        <center><form method = "POST" action="gervent.php">
        <h1>Information </h1>
        Fullname : <input type="text" name="student_name" /><br /><br />
        Student ID No. : <input type="text" name="stud_id" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick=???/>
        </form></center>
        </div>
        <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

gervent.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$name = $_POST['student_name'];
$stud_id = $_POST['stud_id'];
/*Should have this
    $room_id = $_SESSION['roomno'];
    $chair_num = $_SESSION['chairnum'];
*/

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('seat_reservation') or die (mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation WHERE (room_id, chair_number, chair_status, student_name, stud_id) VALUES ($room_id, $chair_num, 1, $name, $stud_id)");

if($insert)
    die ("Seat reserved! <br />Redirecting...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=2;monica.php>");

else 
        die ("Try Again! <br />Redirecting...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=2;monica.php>");
   ?>
```

So gervent.php should get the SESSION values from monica.php so it could use it in inserting. How is it possible in an onclick?
NOTE: say it in simple explanation, i'm too slow for a PHP fast lane. THANKS!

Comment: If the values are already in the session variable, then uncommenting those lines should make it work.  If they aren't, then you're asking the completely wrong question.

Comment: why would you like to set session values on click? when you can set them before the first page load

Comment: The `onclick()` is entirely unnecessary. You're already posting the form to gervent.php.

Comment: sorry about that, don't make me look like it's obvious because it's not for me. I posted here to ask help and not to be scolded. anyway, every time I submit, I want to change the values of the sessions. monica.php is a multiple pop-up asking for information and the value for $_SESSION['chairnum'] and $_SESSION['roomno']should have the values depending on what link s/he clicked.

Comment: actually, using the sessions doesn't work. so i was finding another way in making the gervent.php page get the values.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` variables are not "passed" *per se*. They are maintained between scripts, and so do not require passing. You just set/change them when you want to, and call them anywhere, on server side, you'd like (provided you called `session_start()` at the beginning of the page, but I'm sure you already knew that).

Comment: Not my downvote, but your answer is misleading - the session variable is server-side and javascript can't touch it.

Comment: @bdares Of course it can. You can echo PHP variables into JavaScript. But that's irrelevant anyway because what the OP is trying to achieve really doesn't have anything to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

although it doesn't make sense but only if the session variables are 'specifically' set in the page which the form exists in and they're changed in other pages (i'm saying this because i guess the session variables here seem to be set according to the room page the user has opened and there may be multiple room pages to reserve a seat at with different session variables set each) or if sessions are optional and no sessions has been started in the page the form is in, then you can add hidden input fields to the form which have the values of the room and the chair numbers (and you should find a way to pre-define them into the form, e.g. $_GET['value'], etc.), and you can send them to the target page by clicking submit.

```
<div id="popupContact">
<a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
<center><form method = "POST" action="gervent.php">
<h1>Information </h1>
Fullname : <input type="text" name="student_name" /><br /><br />
Student ID No. : <input type="text" name="stud_id" />
<br /><br />
<!-- the php variables of values has to be set before, any way you'd like -->
<input type="hidden" name="room_id" value="<?=$room_id?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="chair_num" value="<?=$chair_num?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form></center>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

and the page to receive the form values should be like;

```
<?php
session_start();

$name = $_POST['student_name'];
$stud_id = $_POST['stud_id'];
$room_id = isset($_SESSION['roomno']) ? $_SESSION['roomno'] : $_POST['room_id']; // here you set the value according to an already present existance of a session or not
$chair_num = isset($_SESSION['chairnum']) ? $_SESSION['chairnum'] : $_POST['chair_num']; // the same as above but this time for the chair number

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('seat_reservation') or die (mysql_error());
// below sql query is corrected by changing the WHERE clause with COLUMNS
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation COLUMNS (room_id, chair_number, chair_status, student_name, stud_id) VALUES ($room_id, $chair_num, 1, $name, $stud_id)");

if($query) //there was no $insert variable set. This condition would always return false because the sql query which you insert the values to the DB is assigned to $query, not $insert
    die ("Seat reserved! <br />Redirecting...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=2;monica.php>");

else 
    die ("Try Again! <br />Redirecting...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=2;monica.php>");
?>
```

and there's no need to use any javascript onclick event this way.

Comment: hello nonkertompf! i tried your code and i'm confident that it will work this time but unfortunately, it doesn't insert. i don't know where the problem is. in my DB, i have tables res_id which is auto-increment, room_id, chair_number, student_name, stud_id and chair_status. can you help me on this? i've been re checking my code but i don't know which part is wrong. actually, you understand my problem here. thank you! and by the way, in gervent.php, i only wrote this: $room_id = $_POST['room_id'], is it okay? and the hidden input type value is value="<?='400'?>", doing it right?

Comment: @Monica Negapatan Hi Monica. If your hidden input values are static, you should set the values ordinarily without php tags, as you already know. only if there are more than one rooms to reserve a seat at, you should set them dynamically. e.g.; you can set the values to be inserted into the form in monica.php by getting the room value from the url. and you should have a specific url for each room page in order to be able to do this, like; /monica.php?room=14 thus, you can insert that specific value into the form by using the method GET, like; <?=$GET['room']?>.

Comment: Also the changes you made in your gervent.php is ok. By changing it the way you did, you just don't check anymore if the session variables are set before or not.
Also, at first I didn't take a look at the whole gervent.php for I just paid attention to your question but your sql queries are also not correct. Please take a look at my answer to your question again, note the parts I've edited and change your sql queries like that.

Comment: hi nonkertompf! i just noticed that there was an error in passing the values of chair_num. i echoed it and saw that even if i click pc 04, it has a value of the chair_num as 5. i removed the chair number 5 reservation to try if it really inserts, but it still doesn't. it goes to try again. so, I placed this initialization: <?php $room_id = '400'; $chair_num='3'?> <input type="hidden" name="room_id" value="<?=$room_id?>" /> <input type="hidden" name="chair_num" value="<?=$chair_num?>" /> and it receives it like this: $room_id = $_POST['room_id']; $chair_num = $_POST['chair_num'];

Comment: actually, i have 6 fields in my table and one of it res_id is auto-increment. i researched and did something like this: $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (NULL, $room_id, $chair_num, 1, $name, $stud_id)");
i don't know if that's wrong or not.